# display icon to left of text

Tags: css

In our html we have:

```
<div id="error2"></div>
```

This displays dynamic error message.

In the css I have:

```
#error2 {
    background:url(../images/cross.png) left center no-repeat;
    color: #ff2217;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:absolute;
    top:175px;
    left:32px;
}
```

What I get is:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Comment: it would be nice if ie supported generated content: `#error2:before{content: url(../images/cross.png);}` would be just swell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding some padding:

```
#error2 {
padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-left:;` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8DnTa/